# Last commit every day on a specifig branch

Tags: git

How can I get a list of last commit made every day on a specific branch. Would it contain merges to that branch or not? Can we separate it? Would merges count as one commit?

Comment: You won't be able to do all that in git, you'll need to process the output from `git log`: what OS are you using?

Comment: Linux, I have as OS.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get a list of last commit made every day on a specific branch.

`git log --since=1.day -1`

> Would it contain merges to that branch or not?

Yes it would.

> Can we separate it?

If you do `rebase`'s instead of `merge`'s to that branch.

> Would merges count as one commit?

Yes if you do merges to your branch instead of rebases.

**Update**: You can do `git log --since=1.day -1 --no-merges` to avoid showing the merge commit

Comment: Use `--no-merges` with `git log` to ignore merge commits.

Comment: `git log --since=1.day -1` this doesn't print anything for me.

Comment: @auselen Seems you don't have any recent commits after last day. Please check the last commit date using `git log`.

Comment: May be I didn't understand your example, you mean I should say "--since=2018-11-22 -1" ?

Comment: `--since=2018-11-22 -1` will give you all recent commits after 22nd Nov 2018. `--since=1.day` means all recent commits after 21st Nov 2018.

Comment: It looks like I need to wrap git log in a script to get it for each day.

Comment: @auselen yes, you'll have to do that.